# Difference between Deduction and Induction

Tags: logic, philosophy

I would like to know what is the difference between deduction and induction. Mathematical induction I know well, but now I would like to look at these from a philosophical point of view.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I think that induction is based on making conclusion based on previous examples, such as "3,5,7 are primes, so every odd integer $>1$ is a prime". Deduction is based on logical reasoning rather than examples, such as "If we know that A imples B and A is true, then also B is true". But I'm no philospher, let's see if someone has a better answer... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematical induction is a form of deduction and is, in my opinion, poorly named. As far as I know, 'philosophical' induction is reasoning based on shear probability, i.e. 'There is so-and-so evidence to believe that...' For instance, most court cases are decided based on (overall) inductive reasoning.

The reason mathematical induction is a form of deduction is that the logic is clearly enunciated. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction) for more.

Comment: Sometimes "induction" is used for any kind of reasoning that is not deductive. However, usually it is used in a much more restricted sense and may be understood to only apply to cases like "all A-things observed so far have had property B, so therefore all A-things have property B". Everything in between is then called "abduction", and I think that is the most reasonable term to use for what goes on in court cases.